# How to include a local framework in Podspec

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I'm creating a `Podspec` file and need to include two frameworks which I downloaded - one for the Simulator and another for arm64.

I checked https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#specification but couldn't find details of how to include a local framework.

So, I've the two frameworks under the `frameworks` directory as

- `frameworks/debug/local.framework` (for i386)
- `frameworks/release/local.framework` (for arm64)

Has anybody done similar work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this using the below key:

```
s.vendored_frameworks
```

Found this from [here](https://github.com/yutao86/PodspecExample)